# CMAKE wont install OPENCV

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, terminal, cmake

Having loads of problems trying to make my own Haar Cascade Classifier using Opencv. I have followed this tutorial (https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/) and with initial success I have been unable to replicate my results. I have turned to the Opencv Documentation and it has suggested using CMAKE but I keep getting the following error;

[image: CMAKE PROBLEM]

Im sure its something simple but i cant see it. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Positional (non-option) parameter to `cmake` is *source directory*; use it for specify directory with `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: you don't have to put a space after `-D`  so it should be `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`. Also, it is recommended to create a build folder and cmake from there `cmake ..`, this way is easier to clean the project

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is build a temporary folder in the OPENCV directory. Go into the new directory. Then type;

```
cmake /root/opencv/
```

In the new folder and type

```
make
```

then;

```
sudo make install
```